# React router v6 crashes on refreshing

Tags: react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working with react-router v6 it works fine in development mode(on refreshing the website does not crash and works fine) but in production when I refresh the website crashes else navigation is fine

[image]

my code is,

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes
} from "react-router-dom";
//all the import of components

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home></Home>} />
          <Route exact path="/shop" element={<Shop></Shop>} />
          <Route path="/shop/:slug" element={<Product />} />
          <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart></Cart>} />
          <Route path="*" element={<h1>not found</h1>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with Netlify, when I deployed it on Vercel it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and for me, helps to create `_redirects` file with `/*    /index.html   200` content inside the public folder